# Converting Jtable to excel,updated file error

Tags: java, excel, swing, apache-poi, xlsx

I have wriiten a code to create jTable and export  to Excel.I works.But when I open the Excel file the file is not fully recovered.
It shows the following problem:

Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part with XML error.  Load error. Line 2, column 0.
Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet7.xml part with XML error.  Load error. Line 2, column 0.
Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)
Removed Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GUI {
    private static JTextField textField;
    private static JTextField textField_1;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Object rowData[][] = null ;
    Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new    DefaultTableModel(rowData,columnNames);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.setModel(model);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setBounds(76, 106, 300, 200);
    scrollPane.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(76, 21, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(76, 61, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Name");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(20, 24, 46, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblAge = new JLabel("Age");
    lblAge.setBounds(20, 64, 46, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblAge);



    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Get Data");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(235, 40, 89, 23);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String name = textField.getText().toString();
            int age = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
            model.addRow(new Object[] {name,age});
            Object obj1 = GetData(table, 0,0 );
            System.out.println("Cell value of 1 column and 1 row :" + obj1);
            Object obj2 = GetData(table, 0,1 );
            System.out.println("Cell value of 2 column and 1 row :" + obj2);

        }
    });



    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Excel");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            try {
                writeToExcel(table);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(340, 40, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
    frame.setSize(455, 356);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }



protected static void writeToExcel(JTable table) throws Exception {

    try {
        File file = new File("IET.xlsx");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sh = workbook.getSheet("UserInputs");
        TableModel model = table.getModel();
        String value1 = model.getValueAt(0, 0).toString();
        String value2 = model.getValueAt(0, 1).toString();

        workbook.getSheet("UserInputs").getRow(8).getCell(1).setCellValue(value2);


    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    workbook.close();
    System.out.println("File written successfully");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print(e);}
    }



private static Object GetData(JTable table, int x, int y) {

    return table.getValueAt(x, y).toString();
}
  }
```

Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Probably not related to the immediate problem, but.. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Shouldn't `workbook.write(fileOut);` be `workbook.write(fileOut); fileOut.flush();`?

Comment: I only can reproducing the behavior "Removed Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)" if and only if the cell `B9` in sheet `UserInputs` is a heading cell of a table object within the sheet. But why are you trying overwriting the headings of the Excel table with content cell content of the JTable? So to get help you need describing what content is in `IET.xlsx` and what exactly you are trying to do with that content.

Comment: UserInput sheet is a user interface for an application.It has macros, I am trying to use java code instead of macro.

Comment: `IET.xlsx` cannot have macros. Macros cannot be saved in `*.xlsx` files. And the problem is about `Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part `. So we need to know why and how you wants overwriting a Excel table object. Else no help is possible.

Comment: I know xlsx cannot have macros. I want to convert macro code to java.Basically I need my output in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only does overwriting one cell `B9` in sheet `UserInputs`. If this leads to the problem:

"Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part with XML error. Load error. Line 2, column 0. Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet7.xml part with XML error. Load error. Line 2, column 0. Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook) Removed Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)"

while opening the workbook in Excel, then cell `B9` in sheet sheet `UserInputs` is one of the header cells of a Excel table object. Furthermore at least in sheet2 and in sheet7 are structured table references, such as `=Tablename[Columnname]`, used in formulas and such structured table references also are used in named ranges.

So if `B9` in sheet sheet `UserInputs` is one of the header cells of a Excel table object and is changed now, then at first the table itself is corrupt since one of the column names has changed without updating the table. But also all structured table references, such as `=Tablename[Columnname]`, are corrupt, since `Columnname` has changed without updating all those formulas.

Updating the table headers would be possible using [XSSFTable.updateHeaders](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTable.html#updateHeaders--). But updating all structured table references in all formulas in all sheets and even in all named ranges would be very expensive upto nearly impossible. So I would recommend **not** to change header cells of a Excel table object. Let the header cells as they are and change only the content range of the table.

Example:

Let's have the following `IET.xlsx` file:

[image]

As you see, there is a table named `Table1` in sheet `UserInput` and the headers are in row 9.

Now we can overwriting the content range `B10:F[10+n]` with content from a `JTable` like so:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

class ReadAndWriteExcelHavingTableObject {

 static void writeToExcel(XSSFTable exceltable, JTable table) throws Exception {

  int exceltableStartRow = exceltable.getStartRowIndex();
  int exceltableStartCol = exceltable.getStartColIndex();

  XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)exceltable.getParent();

  TableModel model = table.getModel();

  int exceltableEndRow = exceltableStartRow + model.getRowCount(); //as much rows as are in the model
  int exceltableEndCol = exceltable.getEndColIndex();

  //write the content
  for (int r = 0; r < model.getRowCount(); r++) {
   for (int c = 0; c < exceltableEndCol - exceltableStartCol + 1; c++) {
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(exceltableStartRow + 1 + r);
    if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(exceltableStartRow + 1 + r);
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(exceltableStartCol + c);
    if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(exceltableStartCol + c);

    if (c < model.getColumnCount() && model.getValueAt(r, c) instanceof String) {
     String str = (String)model.getValueAt(r, c);
     cell.setCellValue(str);
    } else if (c < model.getColumnCount() && model.getValueAt(r, c) instanceof Double) {
     Double value = (Double)model.getValueAt(r, c);
     cell.setCellValue(value);
    } else if (c >= model.getColumnCount()) { //formula cells
     XSSFCell firstCell = sheet.getRow(exceltableStartRow + 1).getCell(exceltableStartCol + c);
     if (firstCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA) { 
      cell.setCellFormula(firstCell.getCellFormula());
     }
    }
   }
  }

  //update the size of exceltable
  exceltable.setCellReferences(new AreaReference(
    new CellReference(exceltableStartRow, exceltableStartCol),
    new CellReference(exceltableEndRow, exceltableEndCol),
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007));

 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Object rowData[][] = {
          {"Bob", 12.0, 3.0},
          {"Alice", 34.0, 2.5},
          {"Jack", 56.0, 2.0},
          {"John", 78.0, 1.5}
          };
  Object columnNames[] = {"Name", "Amount", "Factor"};
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
  JTable table = new JTable(model);
  table.setModel(model);

  File file = new File("IET.xlsx");
  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

  XSSFTable exceltable = workbook.getTable("Table1");

  writeToExcel(exceltable, table);

  workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
  workbook.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Result will be:

[image]

And since no headers are changed, the table itself and all structured references will be not corrupt after this.